# rootユーザーでの環境変数の値を確認する

Tags: bash, shellscript, sudo

`sudo`した後の環境変数の値を知りたいです。たとえば、rootユーザーの`$PATH`の中身を出力したいです。

試しに`$FOO`の中身を知りたいと思って単純に`echo`してもダメで、これだと現在のユーザーにおける`$FOO`が展開されてから`sudo`の先のコマンドが実行されてしまいます。

```
$ FOO=bar
$ sudo FOO=foo echo $FOO
bar
$
```

一体どのように書けば実現できるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo printenv FOO
```

エスケープも変数中の改行も気にする必要がありません。

`echo $FOO`は$FOOに含まれる文字によっては意図せぬ結果を招きます

```
% FOO='*'
% echo $FOO
1.pdf 2.txt 3.png ...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo FOO=foo env |grep '^FOO='
```

環境変数に改行が含まれていると駄目だけど。

Comment: なるほど！ 確かにこうすればシェルによる展開を気にせずに書けますね。ありがとうございます。